# Check if Go import path is local

Tags: go, import, path, relative-path

Is there a programmatic way (other than manual path parsing) to check whether an import path in Go is local? I can do it manually, but I'd prefer to avoid a buggy implementation.

Comment: With the exception of `go get` subcommand, the Go tool works with local files only.  Are you asking how to determine if local files were created by fetching a remote repo using `go get` or some other tool? Oh, I see the relative tag on the Q.  Are you asking how to determine if a path is relative?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I'm not sure what the terminology is. As in `../foo` vs `net/http` or `github.com/foo/blah`.

Comment: You should not use relative import paths. They work in some cases, but are discouraged for anything other than simple tests. You have to parse the source to figure out the import path used.

Comment: I know. I'm writing a tool to detect import paths - this isn't about my code.

Comment: Ok, then you simply parse the code and check for paths that start with `.`

Comment: My intuition says that's complete, but I'd prefer a library function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [build.IsLocalImport](https://godoc.org/go/build#IsLocalImport) to determine if an import path is local.

> IsLocalImport reports whether the import path is a local import path, like ".", "..", "./foo", or "../foo".